# Add tools.jar in the classpath of sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.9, javap, tools.jar

The ':javap' command in the scala 2.9.1 console need the tools.jar (from JDK6) in the 'classpath'. From cmd-line it could be done with '-cp' argument or CLASSPATH environment variable.

How to do the same for scala console that invoked from SBT with the 'console' and 'console-quick' commands?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Long answer, that might help you elsewhere.

If I want to know about something in SBT, I [`inspect`](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Inspecting-Settings) it:

```
> inspect console
[info] Task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Starts the Scala interpreter with the project classes on the classpath.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/home/dcs/github/anti-xml/}default-39679a/compile:console
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:compilers(for console)
[info]  compile:full-classpath
[info]  compile:scalac-options(for console)
[info]  compile:initial-commands(for console)
[info]  compile:streams(for console)
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:console
[info]  *:console
[info]  {.}/compile:console
[info]  {.}/*:console
[info]  */compile:console
[info]  */*:console
[info] Related:
[info]  test:console
```

Ok, there's an interesting dependency in `compile:full-classpath`. I wish it were `compile:full-classpath(for console)`, but it isn't. It shouldn't cause me trouble in this case, though. Let's `inspect` it.

```
> inspect compile:full-classpath
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]]
[info] Description:
[info]  The exported classpath, consisting of build products and unmanaged and managed, internal and external dependencies.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/home/dcs/github/anti-xml/}default-39679a/compile:full-classpath
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:exported-products
[info]  compile:dependency-classpath
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:console
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:full-classpath
[info]  *:full-classpath
[info]  {.}/compile:full-classpath
[info]  {.}/*:full-classpath
[info]  */compile:full-classpath
[info]  */*:full-classpath
[info] Related:
[info]  compile:full-classpath(for doc)
[info]  test:full-classpath
[info]  test:full-classpath(for doc)
[info]  *:full-classpath(for console)
[info]  runtime:full-classpath
[info]  compile:full-classpath(for console)
```

Ok, I could go further into the dependencies, but I don't think it's necessary. Let's see what's inside it:

```
> show compile:full-classpath
[warn] Credentials file /home/dcs/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] List(Attributed(/home/dcs/github/anti-xml/target/scala-2.9.1/classes), Attributed(/home/dcs/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.1/lib/scala-library.jar))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 7, 2011 3:49:30 PM
```

Ok, nothing unexpected there. Let's add `tools.jar`.

To change something I have to use `set`, and I have to respect a bunch of camel case and other rules to get it working. If I had `compile:full-classpath(for console)`, that would become `fullClasspath in Compile in console`. Note the uppercase in `Compile`, and that `full-classpath` became `fullClasspath`, and the general reordering of element names. [Details here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Scopes).

I think one should be able to take the output of `show` (or, at least, `inspect`) and feed it right back to `set`, but that's not the case (for now, anyway), so just learn these conversions rules.

I don't want to retype everything, just add one JAR file. I need to use `+=` for that. The operators used to change thing can be found [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-More-About-Settings).

The classpath seems to need some `Attributed` stuff. Check the detailed docs on [Classpath](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Classpaths) in the SBT wiki, and figure how to come up with one. Fortunately, most values I may want to change aren't as difficult to create as this one.

```
> set fullClasspath in Compile += Attributed.blank(file("/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/lib/tools.jar"))
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to anti-xml (in build file:/home/dcs/github/anti-xml/)
```

Seems to have worked. Let's `show` its content to confirm, since even writing `compile` instead of `Compile` might get it to change the wrong thing.

```
> show compile:full-classpath                                                                             
[warn] Credentials file /home/dcs/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] List(Attributed(/home/dcs/github/anti-xml/target/scala-2.9.1/classes), Attributed(/home/dcs/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.1/lib/scala-library.jar), Attributed(/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/lib/tools.jar))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 7, 2011 3:50:07 PM
```

Yep, there it is. Let's test it:

```
> console
[warn] Credentials file /home/dcs/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
import com.codecommit.antixml._
bookstore: com.codecommit.antixml.Elem = <bookstore><book><title>For Whom the Bell Tolls</title><author>Hemmingway</author></book><book><title>I, Robot</title><author>Isaac Asimov</author></book><book><title>Programming Scala</title><author>Dean Wampler</author><author>Alex Payne</author></book></bookstore>
books: com.codecommit.antixml.Zipper[com.codecommit.antixml.Elem] = <book><title>For Whom the Bell Tolls</title><author>Hemmingway</author></book><book><title>I, Robot</title><author>Isaac Asimov</author></book><book><title>Programming Scala</title><author>Dean Wampler</author><author>Alex Payne</author></book>
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :javap com.codecommit.antixml.Elem
Compiled from "node.scala"
public class com.codecommit.antixml.Elem extends java.lang.Object implements com.codecommit.antixml.Node,com.codecommit.antixml.Selectable,scala.ScalaObject,scala.Product,scala.Serializable{
    public static final scala.Function1 tupled();
    public static final scala.Function1 curry();
    public static final scala.Function1 curried();
    public static final boolean isValidName(java.lang.String);
    public scala.collection.Iterator productIterator();
    public scala.collection.Iterator productElements();
    public java.lang.Object $bslash(com.codecommit.antixml.Selector, com.codecommit.antixml.CanBuildFromWithZipper);
    public java.lang.Object $bslash$bslash(com.codecommit.antixml.Selector, com.codecommit.antixml.CanBuildFromWithZipper);
    public java.lang.Object $bslash$bslash$bang(com.codecommit.antixml.Selector, com.codecommit.antixml.CanBuildFromWithZipper);
    public java.lang.Object select(com.codecommit.antixml.Selector, com.codecommit.antixml.CanBuildFromWithZipper);
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Zipper toZipper();
    public scala.Option prefix();
    public java.lang.String name();
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Attributes attrs();
    public scala.collection.immutable.Map scope();
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Group children();
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Elem canonicalize();
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Group toGroup();
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Group copy$default$5();
    public scala.collection.immutable.Map copy$default$4();
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Attributes copy$default$3();
    public java.lang.String copy$default$2();
    public scala.Option copy$default$1();
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Elem copy(scala.Option, java.lang.String, com.codecommit.antixml.Attributes, scala.collection.immutable.Map, com.codecommit.antixml.Group);
    public int hashCode();
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public java.lang.String productPrefix();
    public int productArity();
    public java.lang.Object productElement(int);
    public boolean canEqual(java.lang.Object);
    public com.codecommit.antixml.Elem(scala.Option, java.lang.String, com.codecommit.antixml.Attributes, scala.collection.immutable.Map, com.codecommit.antixml.Group);
}
```

Success!!!

Of course, this session is a lie. It took much longer for me to arrive there, but that's mostly practice.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, for detailed answer.

Comment: With SBT 0.12.0 I get:
$ sbt console
scala> set fullClasspath in Compile += Attributed.blank(file("/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/lib/tools.jar"))
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
       set fullClasspath in Compile += Attributed.blank(file("/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/lib/tools.jar"))

Comment: Not sure which SBT version this happened, but now the dependency is `compile:console::fullClasspath` like you wished. `fullClasspath in Compile in console` works.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/blob/master/build.sbt#L35

```
// epic hack to get the tools.jar JDK dependency
val JavaTools = List[Option[String]] (
  // manual
  sys.env.get("JDK_HOME"),
  sys.env.get("JAVA_HOME"),
  // osx
  try Some("/usr/libexec/java_home".!!.trim)
  catch {
    case _: Throwable => None
  },
  // fallback
  sys.props.get("java.home").map(new File(_).getParent),
  sys.props.get("java.home")
).flatten.map { n =>
  new File(n + "/lib/tools.jar")
}.find(_.exists).getOrElse (
  throw new FileNotFoundException (
    """Could not automatically find the JDK/lib/tools.jar.
      |You must explicitly set JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME.""".stripMargin
  )
)
```